# Running a smoke set of JUnit Selenium tests in Jenkins

Tags: selenium, junit, jenkins

How could I easily run only a smoke set of JUnit Selenium tests in Jenkins? Ant is used to execute tests, but I haven't found a way to annotate tests in JUnit and Java. In .NET and C# tests can be annotated, and easily grouped and categorized. I could of course set the Ant target to execute a Java package called "SmokeTests" and have the smoke tests there, but then the smoke tests would reside in two places (duplicate): smoke package and their original package where they belong to.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the last versions of JUnit, there is a way to annotate tests.

They call it categories: https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Categories

You should be able to create a "smoke" category and launch only this one from Jenkins.